# Styling Multiple Menus in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF and am trying to figure out how to customize menus for a Windows 7 touch screen application. I'm using the xaml below that was taken from another question on StackOverflow to style one of the menus. I now want to style another menu that will be used in a different way. How would I style another menu of the same type?

If the answer should be simple / something I should be able to figure out, please post a link to where I can read on how to do this type of thing. I've been reviewing MSDN for a while now and while I'm reading all sorts of stuff I already know, I'm not seeing anything helpful for me here. (Sorry, just discouraged by the constant battle to find basic information I need to complete a simple task.)

```
<Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                        <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource userContextMenuBorder}"
                            Background="{DynamicResource userContextMenuBackground}"
                            MinWidth="182"
                            MinHeight="60"
                            >

                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                >
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!-- SimpleStyles: MenuItem -->

        <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource userContextMenuSeparatorBorder}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!-- TopLevelHeader -->

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border Name="Border" >
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter 
                            Margin="6,3,6,3" 
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                        <Popup 
                            Name="Popup"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                            AllowsTransparency="True" 
                            Focusable="False"
                            PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <Border 
                          Name="SubmenuBorder"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                          Background="{DynamicResource userCMSubmenuBackground}"
                          BorderBrush="{DynamicResource userCMSubmenuBorder}"
                          BorderThickness="1" >
                            <StackPanel  
                                IsItemsHost="True" 
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource userContextMenuHighlightedBackground}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource userContextMenuHighlightedBorder}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource userContextMenuForeground}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- SubmenuHeader -->

        <ControlTemplate 
  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" 
  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border Name="Border" Background="{DynamicResource userCMSubmenuHeaderBackground}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Name="Icon"
        Margin="6,0,6,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ContentSource="Icon"/>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Name="HeaderHost"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
        Margin="5,2,2,2"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <Path 
        Grid.Column="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z" 
        Fill="#404040" />
                    <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Right"
        HorizontalOffset="-4" 
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <Border 
          Name="SubmenuBorder"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Background="#FFFFFF"
          BorderBrush="#888888"
          BorderThickness="1" >
                            <StackPanel  
            IsItemsHost="True" 
            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="#EEEEEE" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- MenuItem Style -->

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Do you need 2 different styles for different ContextMenu?

Comment: Yes. The context menu will be different depending on where it is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your styles different keys:

```
<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" x:Key="MyStyle1">
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" x:Key="MyStyle2">
</Style>
```

You then need to specify which style you want your ContextMenu to use

```
<ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource MyStyle1}"></ContextMenu>

<ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource MyStyle2}"></ContextMenu>
```

If you had any shared style for these ContextMenus, you could do this:

```
<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" x:Key="BaseStyle"></Style

<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" x:Key="MyStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" x:Key="MyStyle2" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
</Style>
```

MyStyle1 and MyStyle2 would then inherit any styles from BaseStyle

All the information I provided could be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So how would I implement that with the current styles that are using keys already: IE `{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}`

Comment: In order to have multiple styles, you need to have multiple keys.  So you can still use the static key for one of your styles, but to have an alternate style, you will need to define a new key, such as the the examples in the answer.  However, for these alternate styles, you will need to manually assign the style to each of the items that you want to style differently...

Comment: I can't manually assign those styles since the menu items are created dynamically.

Comment: You can set a different style for the different menus right?  For each menu you can create a style with a different ItemTemplate

Comment: If this is still unclear, I may need to see what the rest of your xaml looks like (not just the Window.Resources)

Comment: ... `<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">` This style modifies the MenuItem Separator. Since the `Key` is already being used to designate that it is for the separator, how would I assign that to the specific menu I am trying to apply it to. Or am I misunderstanding how the key {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey} is actually being used?

Comment: When you use the static "MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey" you are setting the style for all MenuItem Separator's in your application.  But in your case you would like more than 1 style.  So you will need to replace "{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" with your own key, like "SeparatorStyle1"

Comment: The difference when using your own style keys, however, is that you will need to explicitly associate the style with the control.  What you are doing now is called an implicit style

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43138/discussion-between-tom-and-patrick-y)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining the styles for the child objects in the styles style.resources.

```
    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu" x:Key="UserMenu">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                    <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource userContextMenuBorder}"
                            Background="{DynamicResource userContextMenuBackground}"
                            MinWidth="182"
                            MinHeight="60"
                            >

                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                >
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- SimpleStyles: MenuItem -->

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource userContextMenuSeparatorBorder}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style>
```